# pic18F4550 code protection

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, protection

I use PIC18F4550 in my board and it is "read protected". But I want to have more security by changing the part number of the micro to another part number. This way if someone cracks the code, the code will not work correctly for another micro controller. How can I change the part number?

Comment: What part number? The one painted on top of the chip?

Comment: You'd better ask the mods to remove this question too, it also includes your part number ;-)

Comment: When the programmer detect a device, It uses an ID number which is in one the address lines of the micro controller. I mean that number.

Comment: The ID is hard coded and can not be changed nor protected. You wrote you used "code protection" to prevent read-out via programmer. Did you also set "write protection" and "table read protection" to prevent someone placing own code on the PIC, which transfers the memory via any interface? (code protection does not protect the code from being read by the code itself...)

Comment: No I didn't protect write boot block, write code, write configuration and write EEPROM. If do that can I write the device for another time?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that these chips are not designed to be able to do that. The usual method to achieve this sort of thing is to remove access to the icsp pins (ex a drop of potting epoxy poured over top of the chip with no traces leading off with your icsp).